# Changing a field title in a panel

Tags: panels

I've got a field in a panel. I want the field title to be replaced by something that is dependent on another node. In a view this is really straightforward:

View -> Configure Field -> Rewrite Results -> Rewrite the output of this field: ([field_A] is the name of this thing)

The Panel, however, doesn't recognize the [bracket] functionality in Node -> Settings -> Override title.

Apologies if this is obvious, but I can't find the solution anywhere. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a view of type *content pane* with the *Use panel path* option set to *Yes*?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the Panel tab Content, I've got the title type set to "Manually set", not to "From pane".

Answer (score 1):

You can use **keywords from contexts** when you override a title of a pane in Panels. Go to *Contexts* in the Page Manager UI. The summary of contexts displays the available keywords.

In your situation you may want to add a new context, the node that you want your pane title to be pre-populated from. You can select the node ID, and the same node will always be loaded.

If it's not always the same node that you want to use, but e.g. a reference field in your already loaded node defines it, you can use a relationship to create the appropriate node context.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to override the field title, not the panel title. I need the field title in the Panel to have the same functionality of the field title in a View. In a View, I can click "rewrite the output of this field" to change the title to something like: "[field_A] is great." That View, then, will output "John is great." when field_A = John. Hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your first line. Am trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think keywords are going to get me the custom field title I need that mimics the View "rewrite output" functionality. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please explain why? Context keywords are designed for such a use case you are trying to solve. But maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve. 

Have you succeeded with adding the other node as a context (either manually or through a relationship)? Or do you even need another node? What was the problematic part?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained. I have an integer field. Let's call it "Number of Days". In Views, I can check the "rewrite output" and put "[field_number_of_days] days" so that the output is "3 days", "10 days", etc. instead of the default output of title and value: "Number of days: 3".  In panels, I can't do that. Keywords can create an association with another node, but that's not what I need. I need the title to output based on the value in the field. So, it's not that I need two nodes to have a relationship, it's that I need one node to change its output based on the value of that node.